# Rails 4 : rendering collection in partial with another name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, collections, render

I try to render a collection, using another partial name

in my users_controller#index, the standard list comes with the standard html request , 
corresponding view users/index.html.ham and partial _user.html.haml

I am trying to render differently the user list on Ajax requests , with a different partial

```
index.js.erb
.... 
$(content).html('<%= j render ("album_owner_index", @collection =>  @users, as: album_owner) %>');
```

but this doesn't work , syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' # before collection

if I write only

```
$(content).html('<%= j render("album_owners_index") %>');
```

then it uses the standard _user.html.haml...
anyway to change it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have to use  first in the index.ejs.erb

```
  $(content).html('<%= j render("album_owners_index") %>');
```

then in the partial _album_owners_index.html.haml, i have to render the @users collection , with the as: parameter ... to use another partial rather than the _user one :

```
  = render :partial => "backoffice/users/album_owner", :collection => @users, as: :album_owner
```